# Is there a way to bypass forgerock openam login page using auth chains

Tags: authentication, openam, forgerock

Bypassing the login page so that it will directly in otp page Keeping in mind I know the username and password already.
Is there a way to do this in openam

Comment: Is this like two factor and the user already provided username/password or did the user authenticated beforehand with OpenAM?

Comment: I have given otp verfication. The username and password will be stored in aws parameter store. So basically its like a common credentials but has to verify with otp or any other mfa to enhance security

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Do you have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Forgerock allows you to create custom links for custom login pages using service get parameter, soemthing like:

```
https://yourfqdn/openam/XUI/?realm=/users&service=OTPservice
```

OTPservice is a authentication chain that containes only otp login page, however from forgerock side, you need to find a way to tell forgerock wich user is trying to connect, since you dont want the username/password login page. It can be done using session upgrade, which means you create a session using a API call to authenticate your user without humain interaction, and then perform a session upgrade (the OTP login page).